# exponential number

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I knew e=2.692, but don't know how this has been derived (I am not from maths major, but have genuine interest in mathematics), and how it has been used in solving equation, For expample in solving simple harmonic oscillator equation also e has been used, i want explanation in simple terminology.

Comment: If you are referring to the [mathematical constant e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29), then the correct approximation to three decimal points is $e\approx 2.718$.

Comment: Are you referring to the [mathematical constant $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))?

Comment: @David,@Jeppe yes i am referring to mathematical constant e, sorry i have put it as 2.692 instead of 2.718..

Answer (score 1):

$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)^n\approx2.7~1828~1828~45~90~45\ldots$$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) for more details.

Comment: But the $1828$s don't continue (as one might think from the way you wrote it). In fact $e$ is irrational.